# How to write razor custom html helper syntax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor

I have the following code below(c# razor syntax) from code sample at http://weblogs.asp.net/seanmcalinden/archive/2009/12/02/fluent-html-helpers-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx and I am trying to convert to vb.net razor syntax.I tried various things like using "new with" but I cannot figure it out.Any help please?

```
  <%= this.Html.RenderInput
    (
        Attributes.Configure()
            .AddType("submit")
            .AddId("submit_button")
            .AddName("submit.button")
            .AddCssClass("submitButtonCssClass")
    ) %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following Razor VB.NET syntax allowing you to achieve the same:

```
@this.Html.RenderInput( _
    Attributes _
        .Configure() _
        .AddType("submit") _
        .AddId("submit_button") _
        .AddName("submit.button") _
        .AddCssClass("submitButtonCssClass") _
)
```